# Vote to close not possible because it was flagged

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, flag-history

I recently hit 3k on SO and now I can vote to close. I have an extensive flagging history with some of them are marked as *waiting for review*.

I had to discover that the flag from my pre-3k prevents me to vote to close. Since I have quite a few votes left, I would like to convert my flag to a close-vote at the expense of one vote.

Don't get me wrong, I don't want that all my previous flags waiting for review are automatically converted to close-votes (for example at the end of the day if there are still votes left). The questions might already have received a good correcting edit or I made a mistake when I first flagged it. Though, this should be possible on a case by case basis.

Comment: Close flags and close votes are treated the same in the innards of the site now, so the above should answer this question.

Comment: Yes, I see. My search skills are obviously not the best.